# What's the right way to include a browser REPL on a page, but only in development?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm using [Austin](https://github.com/cemerick/austin) to set up a browser-connected REPL, and following the example of its [sample project](https://github.com/cemerick/austin/blob/master/browser-connected-repl-sample/src/clj/cemerick/austin/bcrepl_sample.clj), which uses Enlive to add the REPL script to the page.

Now I'd like to deploy my app, but I don't wan't Austin or my REPL to be on the page in production. What's the intended way to use the REPL only in development?

Is there a way to use Enlive as a middleware I could use in development and not in production?

Comment: If you've installed Austin as described in it's installation section in a [leiningen dev profile](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md), you can use leiningens profile selection mechanism to ensure it's installed or not. This will however not help you with handling the rest of additions you have to make to install Austin (e.g. `require` calls etc.).

Comment: Right, that's what the question is about. How do I add Austin to my page in a way that's profile-dependent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's almost always something that uniquely distinguishes a production environment from `:dev` that you can use as a conditional: if in `:dev`, inject the result of `(browser-connected-repl-js)`; if not, don't.

If your deployment environment doesn't have such a property, I'd suggest adding one, as this sort of "only in environment *X*" use case is pretty common for a lot of things.

---

On the other hand, if you're looking to avoid having Austin and its dependencies included in your production-targeted builds entirely without changing any of your code that uses `browser-connected-repl-js`, one solution might be to simply dummy up the relevant Austin namespace, e.g.:

```
(ns cemerick.austin.repls)

(defn browser-connected-repl-js [& _] "")
```

Put that in `cemerick/austin/repls.clj` in a directory that is included in your `project.clj`'s non-`:dev` profile`:source-paths`. Now your code will deploy to production without Austin and its dependencies, and your code will transparently call the above dummy function (injecting nothing into your page(s)).

Comment: Sounds like it's typically done a little differently for each project then? I can do that, but I was worried I was missing something. The big thing is that I'd rather not have Austin be a depedency/plugin outside of `:dev`, but now it's in the `ns` form of the namespace where my Ring handler lives. Is there a good pattern to make that conditional?

Comment: Edited to suggest a workaround that eliminates the Austin dependency outside of `:dev`. There are other ways that this could be done, but they might require some subtle changes Austin; the suggested approach can be implemented now with little effort.

Comment: Looks like there's a new template that sets things up like you describe: https://github.com/plexus/chestnut